# How is it possible for Numpy to use comma-separated subscripting with `:`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Consider the following example:

```
>>> a=np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a[np.newaxis,:,np.newaxis]
array([[[1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4]]])
```

How is it possible for Numpy to use the `:` (normally used for slicing arrays) as an index when using comma-separated subscripting?

If I try to use comma-separated subscripting with either a Python list or a Python list-of-lists, I get a TypeError:

```
>>> [[1,2],[3,4]][0,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

?

Comment: it can be only used for indexing (of an *existing* list/array). In the latter case, you're using it to create a list

Comment: `[x,y]` passes a tuple `(x,y)` to the item's `__getitem__` method.  Whether that's meaningful or not depends on the class.

Comment: @hpaulj - But why can I pass `:` as an element of a `tuple` then? I.e. `[2,:]` passes `(2,:)`, but `:` is not a value in Python, and so cannot be an element of a `tuple`?

Comment: @Marat - what you are saying, is that `:` can only be used between brackets after an identifier, e.g.  `a[...]`? Will you provide a link to the Python grammar? Furthermore, how can `[3,:]` be equivalent to `[(3,:)]` - if `:` is not a value, then it cannot be an element in a `tuple`?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean. `:` is not a value, and also cannot be an element of a tuple. if you are looking to store indexing parameters, you might use [ellipsis](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/ellipsis.html) instead: `[3, ...]`

Comment: `[3.:]` can also be written as `[(3, slice(None))]`, or `idx = (3, slice(None)); x[idx]`.  In a `[]` context, `:` and `...` are parsed as their `slice` and `Ellipsis` equivalents.  Perhaps the most formal description is here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=slice#slicings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a simple class with a `getitem`, indexing method:

```
In [128]: class Foo():
     ...:     def __getitem__(self, arg):
     ...:         print(type(arg), arg)
     ...: 
In [129]: f = Foo()
```

And look at what different indexes produce:

```
In [130]: f[:]
<class 'slice'> slice(None, None, None)
In [131]: f[1:2:3]
<class 'slice'> slice(1, 2, 3)
In [132]: f[:, [1,2,3]]
<class 'tuple'> (slice(None, None, None), [1, 2, 3])
In [133]: f[:, :3]
<class 'tuple'> (slice(None, None, None), slice(None, 3, None))
In [134]: f[(slice(1,None),3)]
<class 'tuple'> (slice(1, None, None), 3)
```

For builtin classes like `list`, a tuple argument raises an error.  But that's a class dependent issue, not a syntax one.  `numpy.ndarray` accepts a tuple, as long as it's compatible with its shape.

The syntax for a tuple index was added to Python to meet the needs of `numpy`.  I don't think there are any builtin classes that use it.

The `numpy.lib.index_tricks.py` module has several classes that take advantage of this behavior.  Look at its code for more ideas.

```
In [137]: np.s_[3:]
Out[137]: slice(3, None, None)
In [139]: np.r_['0,2,1',[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
Out[139]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [140]: np.c_[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
Out[140]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

other "indexing" examples:

```
In [141]: f[...]
<class 'ellipsis'> Ellipsis
In [142]: f[[1,2,3]]
<class 'list'> [1, 2, 3]
In [143]: f[10]
<class 'int'> 10
In [144]: f[{1:12}]
<class 'dict'> {1: 12}
```

I don't know of any class that makes use of a dict argument, but the syntax allows it.

Comment: Thanks, so just to be sure: only inside `[]` is `:` interpreted as  `slice(None, None, None)`?

Comment: Colon has other uses such as line end and dictionary, but it's interpreted as a `slice` only in the indexing context.  Elsewhere you'll get a syntax error.   (It's also part of the `ipython` line prompt, but that's not python syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

Lists are 1D and you can either pass a single index **or** a slice. The `:` when used for index is a short notation to create a slice. In `[[1,2],[3,4]][0,:]` you are passing `0,:`, which is the tuple `(0, :)`. That is, in order to create a tuple the parenthesis are optional here. Just having values separated by comma will create the tuple.

But numpy is different, since it is a N-dimensional array and not just 1D as lists you can pass *multiple indexes* to index the different dimensions. Therefore, passing a tuple to index numpy is allowed as long as the number of elements in the tuple is not greater than the dimensions of the indexed array. Consuder the array below

```py
arr = np.random.randn(5,10, 3)
```

It has 3 dimensions and we can index it like `arr[0,1,0]`, but this is the same as `arr[(0,1,0)]`. That is, we are passing a tuple to index the array. Each tuple element itself can be an integer or a slice and numpy will do the appropriated indexing. Numpy accepts tuples for indexing but lists don't.

However, when you write `a[np.newaxis,:,np.newaxis]` it is a **more than just indexing**. First, note that `np.newaxis` is just `None`. When you use `None` to index a dimension **in numpy** what it does as creating that dimension. The `a` array in your example is 1D, but `a[np.newaxis,:,np.newaxis]` is a special type of indexing understood by numpy as a short notation to "give me an array with extra axis where I'm indexing with `np.newaxis` and whose elements are from my original array indexed as I'm specifying".

So, the TLDR answer is numpy indexing is more general and powerful than list indexing.

Comment: Thank you. So, is `:` only accepted by Python, when it appears somewhere between brackets `[...]`? For example, it's not possible to write `(1,:)` or just `:` in Python. Also, `:` is not a value, right? It's only syntax - you cannot put it in a `tuple` or similar?

Comment: Use `slice(None)` if you want an slice object in a tuple or non-indexing context.  Or `np.s_[:]` which is a `numpy` "indexing_trick".  `np.s_` docs and/or code might give you more insight as to what's going on.

Comment: You can also do `slice(start, stop, step)`, which is like `start:stop:step` when used in an indexing context. You can do `s = slice(1,10,2)` to get a slice representing from 1 to 10 (not including 10) skipping every other element. Then you can use it to index an array `arr` as `arr[s]`, which is the same as writing `arr[1:10:2]`. Of course you can also pass a tuple containing integers and slices to a numpy array for indexing.